# Create a Odontogram using Applet in Java

Tags: java, applet

Well, I must create a odontogram like image bellow:

[image]

My all system is web (JSF - Primefaces), so i choose Java Applets to create a "powerfull" odontogram. My odontogram must enable that Dentist can click in any face or tooth and paint this. My ideia is: Create all this with JAVA 2D.

This works but will be a hard work, because i must "monitoring" each face in each tooth, do you have some better solution for this ? Or this is the better solution ? (Create all polygons in JAVA 2D)

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Why not create multiple images and serve them in a layout?

Comment: I think a less elegant solution use the HTML to do this, i must create a lot of TAGS, for each face and each tooth and position this in a "ABSOLUTION POSITION with CSS", this is more work, i think! Remeber that i must color each clicked region.